# Как задать всем div с одинаковым классом свойство display:none

Tags: javascript

Хотелось бы замутить это с помощью функции javascript. Можно вообще обратиться к нескольким элементам?

Comment: jQuery:

    $(".className").css('display', 'none');
    // or
    $(".className").hide();

each, я так понимаю для наглядности?

на счёт префиксного инкремента:

    var a = [1,2,3];
    for( var i=0; i<a.length;  ) { console.log( a[++i] ) }
    for( var i=0; i<a.length;  ) { console.log( a[i++] ) }

вот здесь будет заметна разница.

@AlexWindHope, а с вашим кодом всё в порядке

Если быть ещё более максимально дотошным, то цикл `for` сам по себе излишен, т.к. легко заменяется циклом `while`

Comment: я не только про js, я про языки программирования в целом, ведь `for` всего лиш более удобная "обёртка" над циклом `while`, т.е. цикл `while` более общее понятие чем цикл `for`, хотя с таким успехом можно прийти к выводу, что `goto`, т.е. его ассемблерные истоки - это панацея

--------------

и мне кажется это уже офтоп

Comment: Мда, это мне показалось :-)

Comment: @ustal мой ответ это то что вы хотели?

Answer (score 2):

Перебирать элементы по классу и вставлять им инлайн стиль - по-индусски.

```
var stylesheet = document.styleSheets[0];
stylesheet.insertRule( 'div.undisplayed { display: none; }', stylesheet.cssRules.length );
```

Comment: Поскольку я облажался с инкрементом, в качестве епитимьи предлагаю кошерное решение.

Comment: @Rules, поправил, благодарю. Хотя не думаю, что стилистико-грамматическая ошибка тянет не *облажался*, мы же не на форуме филологов. Кстати, регулярка не получилась. Читайте [сюда](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#classes).

Comment: Если бы еще хоть одно условие было - уже бы так не прокатило (ширина < 200 etc). Но задача решена и, кстати, я впервые такое вижу (позор на мою седину), потому плюс)

Comment: @alex_90

> Да @karmadro4 чмо, даже свои ошибки признать не может..

А вы зачем здесь нарисовались? Вы же не разбираетесь в этой теме и не поняли ни слова из написанного. Давайте конкретную критику, а кукарекать прошу в другое место.

Answer (score -3):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>brg</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="divobj someclass" style="left: 0px;">A</div>
<div class="divobj otherclass" style="left: 30px;">B</div>
<div style="left: 60px;">C</div>
<div class="divobj" style="left: 90px;">D</div>
<style>
.divobj{
 position: absolute;
 background-color: #FF0000;
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 top: 0px;
}
</style>
<script>
window.onload=function(){
function getElementsByClassName(where, className){ //Функция работает во всех 
                //браузерах а document.getElementsByClassName везде кроме IE<9
   var allElements = where.getElementsByTagName("*"); //Получаем все тэги
   var elements = [];
   for(var i=0;i<allElements.length;i++){
      if(new RegExp(""+className,"g").test(allElements[i].className)){ // Отсеиваем
                                                                     //по className
         elements.push(allElements[i]);
      }
   }
   return elements; // Возвращяем результат
}
objs=getElementsByClassName(document,"divobj"); // Получаем все обьекты с классом some
for(var i=0;i<objs.length;i++){
   obj=objs[i];
   if(obj.tagName=="DIV"){ // Если дейстаительно это div то
      obj.style.display = "none"; // Присваеваем обьекту свойство
   }  
}
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

P.S: лучшая альтернатива предложена [[@Котик](/users/4149/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82_%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)](/users/4149/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82_%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)'ом: ": [Функции для поиска элементов по классам и тегам](http://ejohn.org/blog/getelementsbyclassname-speed-comparison/)

P.P.S оставлю свой ответ если кому интересно и НЕ МИНУСУЙТЕ! МОЙ КОД ПРЕКРАСНО РАБОТАЕТ!

P.P.P.S обновил код специально для [[@karmadro4](/users/6679/karmadro4)](/users/6679/karmadro4)

Comment: `//Функция неправильно работает во всех браузерах...`

Должно быть так ;-)

Comment: НЕПРАВДА! @karmadro4 Я проверил во всех браузерах всё прекрасно работает! А вы перед тем как меня обвинять и минусовать проверяйте код!!!!

Comment: @Rules Даже если и работает, то все равно коммент @karmadro4 забавный :)

![][1]

[1]: http://i1195.photobucket.com/albums/aa394/TSGIGOR/FUNNY/7.gif

Comment: @Rules

- [**http://ejohn.org/blog/getelementsbyclassname-speed-comparison**][1]

- [**http://www.google.com/trends/?q=jquery,+javascript**][2]

[1]: http://ejohn.org/blog/getelementsbyclassname-speed-comparison/
[2]: http://www.google.com/trends/?q=jquery,+javascript

Comment: @Rules Потому что концептуально правильный ответ уже дал @karmadro4, а следовать принципу [**DRY**][1] - это обычно не самая плохая идея :)

[1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself

Comment: @Rules, чтож вы так кричите-то... 

> МОЙ КОД ПРЕКРАСНО РАБОТАЕТ!

Неправда же, это только говорит о неправильном тестировании. Пари?

Comment: Какие будут ставки? Располагаю 1008 очками и не боюсь проиграть.

Comment: Ставлю 75 очков на победу @Rules. Ради интереса.

Comment: А я понял о чём вы говорили @karmadro4 мой код ищет элементы ТОЛЬКО С ДАННЫМ КЛАССОМ а если присутствуют другие не работает но ведь Хэшкод это не Frilance поэтому моей целью было льшь показать подход (а заменить == на RegExp не составляет труда!) а не писать код за @ustal И вопрос кстати стоял:
> Можно ли вообще обратиться к нескольким элементам?

Comment: Извините @Котик_хочет_кушать что не оправдал ваших надежд :) Но:

1. Мне 16 и я больше занят школой/колледжем а не Хэшкод'ом.

2. Я учу С++ и WEB вспоминаю только ради Хэшкод'а.

3. Как я уже сказал @karmadro4'у  это не frilance а Хэшкод.

4. @karmadro4 сам облажался со своим ответом!

Comment: Фи, никакого азарта... Но зато удалось заставить подумать над кодом и то хорошо. @Rules, отмазка, условие с регулярным выражением запостили до того, как вы начали рекламировать свое решение.

> 4. @karmadro4 сам облажался со своим ответом!

Это где такое показалось?

Comment: А кто написал
>Перебирать выбирать элементы по классу и вставлять им инлайн стиль - по-индусски.
?

Comment: Да @karmadro4 чмо, даже свои ошибки признать не может..